# Assigning a value based on win probability

Tags: probability, game-theory, algorithmic-game-theory

I have a roster of entities which may compete in a competition that involves randomness . Generally if two entities directly compete and would have a win-loss-draw of about 50% (determined using monte-carlo simulation) with each other, we could consider them equivalent and give them the same arbitrary value.

Is there a set of mathematical functions that can determine this, more easily than say simulating varying ratios until you can achieve a 50% win rate (for example, if one entity is twice as valuably as another, that entity might have a 50% win rate paired against two of those opponents simultaneously).

If it is relevant, consider the competition might be similar to dodge-ball. Entities can be eliminated and take no further part in a game, and certain entities might be better at avoiding elimination, or at eliminating opponents. Ultimately, the aim is to fairly score two teams of entities, such that there is a relatively good balance of outcome, based on the sum value of the players compared.

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you are looking for, but ELO (say in chess) is designed such that a rating difference between two opponents predicts the winning probability. Maybe it's connected.

Comment: Thanks. I considered ELO, but two 1000 point players aren't equivalent to a 2000 point player. I'm not sure if there's a mathematical or game theory name for what I'm after, but it's kind of the absolute value, such that you are unbothered whether you have one valuable entity or two half as valuable entities.

Comment: I think that first, you need to specify the additivity in your case. Would you want two 1000 points players to be equal to one 2000, more or less?

Comment: Yes, two 1000points entities would equal one 2000point entity.

Comment: So why not ELO(team)=sum ELO(players in team)?

Comment: Do you have a suggestion for how to practically do that?
For starters, ELO was never designed to be used in multi-player games, right?

Comment: True, but from what you told me: you compare teams, not players AND the team's strength is a simple sum of players' abilities. From that you can just use ELO rating for each player, then when comparing teams compute the team ELO as the sum of the players. I'm not sure if this will give you exactly what you want, but it is one solution. What do you mean by "practically"?

Comment: Ah, that won’t work. The teams are dynamic, so we need to be able to estimate “player” impact. I’m fiddling with Trueskill, which is a bayesian approach similar superficially to ELO but you can have teams, unbalanced teams etc and track individual scoring.